# 2nd step not inserting data

Tags: spring, spring-batch

In my code below, I have defined 2 steps for a job, where each step reads data from a different csv. Here the data from the 1st step gets inserted in the DB, ut the 2nd step is not inserting data in the DB. Can you please help in pointing out the error

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class MacroSimulatorConfiguration {

@Autowired
private JobBuilderFactory jobs;

@Autowired
private StepBuilderFactory steps;

@Bean
public ItemReader<Consumption> reader() {
    FlatFileItemReader<Consumption> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<Consumption>();
    reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("datacons.csv"));
    reader.setLinesToSkip(1);
    reader.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper<Consumption>() {
        {
            setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer() {
                {
                    setNames(new String[] { "tradeCommodity", "hou", "region", "dir", "purchValue", "value" });
                }
            });
            setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Consumption>() {
                {
                    setTargetType(Consumption.class);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    return reader;
}

@Bean
public ItemReader<Gdp> reader1() {
    FlatFileItemReader<Gdp> reader1 = new FlatFileItemReader<Gdp>();
    reader1.setResource(new ClassPathResource("datagdp.csv"));
    reader1.setLinesToSkip(1);
    reader1.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper<Gdp>() {
        {
            setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer() {
                {
                    setNames(new String[] { "region", "gdpExpend", "value" });
                }
            });
            setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Gdp>() {
                {
                    setTargetType(Gdp.class);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    return reader1;
}

@Bean
public ItemWriter<Consumption> writer(DataSource dataSource) {
    JdbcBatchItemWriter<Consumption> writer = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<Consumption>();
    writer.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<Consumption>());
    writer.setSql("INSERT INTO INPUT_CONSUMPTION (TRAD_COMM, HOU, SUB_REGION, INCOME_GROUP, CITIZEN_STATUS, REGION, DIR, PURCHVALUE, VAL) "
            + "VALUES (:tradeCommodity, :hou, :subRegion, :incomeGroup, :citizenStatus, :region, :dir, :purchValue, :value)");
    writer.setDataSource(dataSource);
    return writer;
}

@Bean
public ItemWriter<Gdp> writer1(DataSource dataSource) {
    JdbcBatchItemWriter<Gdp> writer1 = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<Gdp>();
    writer1.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<Gdp>());
    writer1.setSql("INSERT INTO input_gdp (REGION, GDPEXPEND, VAL) " + "VALUES (:region, :gdpExpend, :value)");
    writer1.setDataSource(dataSource);
    return writer1;
}

@Bean
public Job importJob(Step s1, Step s2) {
    return jobs.get("importJob").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).start(s1).next(s2).build();
}

@Bean(name = "s1")
public Step step1(ItemReader<Consumption> reader, ItemWriter<Consumption> writer) {
    return steps.get("step1").<Consumption, Consumption>chunk(100).reader(reader).writer(writer).build();
}

@Bean(name = "s2")
public Step step2(ItemReader<Gdp> reader1, ItemWriter<Gdp> writer1) {
    return steps.get("step2").<Gdp, Gdp>chunk(1).reader(reader1).writer(writer1).build();
}
```

}

This is what I see in console. There is parsing error on 1st csv as there are no records on line 13834 and after that. But records from 1st csv are successfully inserted in the DB, so guessing this parsing error can be ignored. Wondering if the reader, writer, step & job have been correctly defined for 2nd csv.

Console:

```
Job: [SimpleJob: [name=importJob]] launched with the following parameters: [{run.id=1}]
Executing step: [step1]
Encountered an error executing step step1 in job importJob
Parsing error at line: 13834 in resource=[class path resource [datacons.csv]], input=[]
Job: [SimpleJob: [name=importJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{run.id=1}] and the following status: [FAILED]
```

Comment: Do you get an actual error during step2 or is your data simply not inserted? The only thing coming to mind right now is that your step2 tablename is in lowercase whereas step1 is in uppercase and some DBMS are case-sensitive

Comment: I tried changing tablename to uppercase but that didn't help. I have updated my question with the console output.

Comment: are you sure datacons.cvs is present/accessibile in your classpath?

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci yes, I do see all the 13833 records from csv being inserted into the db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see in the console output, your step2 is not executed at all.

This is normal Spring Batch behaviour : If an "[non-skippable](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/configureStep.html)" error is encountered during a step, the step will terminate with the status `FAILED` and so will the job lest you have a `.on("FAILED")` to explicitly prevent default behaviour and call another step.

Also, you may wonder why you still have records inserted in your database, this is due to the fact that Spring Batch commit records according to the `commit-interval` you defined. Since you set it to 1, every record preceding the one in error will be commited.

So, here you have 3 solutions :

- Prevent the parse error in the file
- Add skippable exceptions class (either your ParseException or simple `java.lang.Exception`). This will tell Spring Batch to ignore errors and continue reading the file.
- Explicitly declare a transition `.on("*")` between first and second step to start the second one even if the first one fails. The first file will only be read up to the first error, then the second file will be read.

Comment: Oh thanks. This info was helpful. Regarding bullet#3, are you saying to try this way? `return jobs.get("importJob").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).start(s1).on("*").next(s2).build();` as this line is now giving error

Comment: @dazzle `.on("*")` requires either a flow or a decider. Take a look here : https://narmo7.wordpress.com/2014/05/14/spring-batch-how-to-setup-a-flow-job-with-java-based-configuration/

Comment: very helpful. You have been awesome!